# jquery ajax php results in unidentified index

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

when I try to use an ajax-method via jquery I always receive the "unidentified index" message of the targeted php file.

The interesting stuff. "Debugging" methods with console.log() in jquery AND the firebug network window are showing me that the data is sent! But it seems that the data doesn't get to the php file. Well, when I send the data the usualy way with php (post) there is no problem. I find that behaviour very (!) strange.

I already asked developers I know but they couldn't help me with this problem. Maybe I (or we) are overlooking something?

the php/html with the form:

```
    <form method="post" action="configurator2.php">

        <label>Name der Navigation</label>
        <br />
        <input type="text" name="menuname" />
        <br />

        <input class="button" type="button" value="ajax it" />
        <input class="button1" type="submit" value="php only" />
    </form>

    <div class="result"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $(".button").click(function() {
      var menuname = $('form input[name=menuname]').val();
            $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'configurator2.php',
            data:{menuname:menuname},
            dataType:'html',
            success:function() {
              $('.result').load('configurator2.php');
          }
          });
    });

  });
</script>
```

and here the php:

```
$name = $_POST["menuname"];
echo $name;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`load` here fires another query to the server, this time without parameters, causing the error. The actual result is already received. To display it on the page, just use received data:

```
success:function(data) {
    $('.result').html(data);
}
```